# Irregular display when printing functions

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a script that when called prompts a user for a string and it displays the string forward, backward, tests if 2 strings are the same, and tests if a string is a palindrome.  I want to test the individual functions for correctness before I input a menu, however the output when calling palindrome() function seems irregular.  Any help on why the two statements in the palindrome() function prints this way would be appreciated.

```
string = raw_input('Enter a string\n>>>')

def forward():
    for i in string:
        print i,
    return str(i)

def backwards():
    back = len(string) - 1
    while back > 0:
        print string[back],
        back -= 1
    return str(string[back])

def match():
    next_string = raw_input('Enter another string')
    if string.upper() == next_string.upper():
        print 'the strings ', string, ' and ', next_string, ' match.'
    else:
        print 'the strings ', string, ' and ', next_string, ' do not match.'

def palindrome():
    print backwards() # When I don't print this call it only displays the last value in the string
    y = forward() # When I do print this call it displays the last value in the string twice
    # This is the only way where these calls are opposite

palindrome()
```

Comment: `forward` has a print in it.

Comment: @hobbs I understand, that's why I'm so confused about why only the last value is printed in backward() and the last value is repeated when forward() is called